# rails change the background of my like button when clicks on it :

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, erb, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm in the last step of my rails application (instagram-clone ) , and the issue is when i click on heart logo the count of number of likes upgraded from 0 to 1 but , i can't find the solution to change the background color of my logo to "red" when i click on it, [this is my logo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPREE.png)

this is my vote.js.erb:

```
<% if current_user.liked? @post %>
    $(".like-button").addClass("liked");
<% else %>
    $(".like-button").removeClass("like-button");
<% end %>
$(".likes-count").html(" <%= @post.get_upvotes.size%> ")

#i want to modify this lines to change the background color of my heart logo to red when the count of likes was upgraded from 0 to 1 and thanks a lot
```

this i s my like button code lines :

```
<%= link_to like_post_path(post),  class:"like-button", method: :put, remote: :true do %>
    <div>
      <i class="fas fa-heart fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
    <% end %>
<span class="likes-count"><%= post.get_upvotes.size %></span>
```

[image]

Comment: The ruby templates are rendered server side, right?

Comment: where is that logo ? Please show [mcve]

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add additional information, see [mcve] - specifically we would want to see how your "logo" is rendered - eg is it just an image without a transparent background?

Comment: Try : `$(".like-button i.fa-heart").css("background-color", "red")` after `$(".like-button").addClass("liked");` line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is your option.
There could be many stories/photos you might be looking and scrolling through the list.

Here is the fix that suit this kind of scenarios.

Some changes in vote.js.erb:

```rb
<% if current_user.liked? @post %>
    $(".like-button-<%= @post.id %> .fas").addClass("liked");
<% else %>
    $(".like-button-<%= @post.id %> .fas").removeClass("liked");
<% end %>

$(".likes-count").html(" <%= @post.get_upvotes.size%> ")
```

---

As you are using icon, Somewhere in the style add css similar to below.

```css
  .liked {
    color: red;
  }
```

---

And some changes in your html button

```rb
<%= link_to like_post_path(post),  class: "like-button-#{post.id}", method: :put, remote: :true do %>
    <div>
      <i class="fas fa-heart fa-2x <%= 'liked' if current_user.liked?(post) %>"></i>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thank you very much @Hiren understand the concept exactly , but when i'm trying to do this , i get this error : undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass in this line ` <i class="fas fa-heart fa-2x <%= 'liked' if current_user.liked?(@post) %>"></i>`

Comment: Oops, sorry updated that line in answer. Just need to remove `@` before the `post`.

Comment: thanks bro for you're time, the count of likes still works but the background color doesn't change . i think i have problem in my class names or something like that ...

Comment: please check if the give class of css is applied to the tag/element?

Comment: Yes it is@hiren :)

Comment: I think there is another issue because I right the same code...

Comment: By any chance you can share any screenrecord of your browser console where we can see the list of element and related css on the right side.

Comment: you can see now my css element above , thank you very much :)

Comment: try adding `!important` to that css property.
like 
`color: red !important`

Comment: yeeeeees , finally it's work , thank you very much my friend :) :) :)

Comment: how , because i'm new in stackoverflow  , tell me how and i wanna give you 10 X upvote :)

Comment: Just click the up arrow, on the left top side of answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233266/discussion-between-fazaa-majdeddine-and-hiren-bhalani).

Comment: it's ok my friend